# Add visual editor capability to custom excerpt window?

Tags: editor, html, excerpt, formatting

The custom excerpt field (under Add New Post) only accepts html. Thus, you can't just cut and paste a segment from the Visual Editor. If you want links to appear in custom excerpt, you have to know how to create them.

This doesn't work so well for users who are unfamiliar with html. Is there any way to give the same Visual Editor capabilities to the custom excerpt field?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin [TinyMCE Excerpt](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-excerpt/) adds the Visual Editor to the Excerpt field.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-excerpt/